# Set-theoretic minimum and maximum of two stopping times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stopping-times

I have a confusion about stopping times and hope you can help me there!

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be stopping times with values in $I=\big[0,\infty)$ with respect to the filtration $\mathbb{F} = (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in I}$.

So for $t \in I$ by definition we have $\{\tau \leq t \} = \{\omega \in \Omega: \tau(\omega) \leq t\} = A_{\tau} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ and $\{\sigma \leq t \} = \{\omega\in \Omega: \sigma(\omega) \leq t\} = A_{\sigma} \in \mathcal{F}_t$. My book now says that the minimum $\{\tau \wedge \sigma \leq t \} = \{\tau \leq t \}\cup \{\sigma \leq t \}$ and the maximum $\{\tau \vee \sigma \leq t \} = \{\tau \leq t \}\cap \{\sigma \leq t \}$. Why are they union and intersection of the stopping times?

Comment: If $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma -$algebra, then $A,B\in \mathcal F\implies A\cap B\in \mathcal F$ and $A\cap B\in \mathcal F$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't see the connection of the maximum (minimum) with the intersection (union) of the stopping times tho. That union and intersection of two sets of $\mathcal{F}$ are again in $\mathcal {F}$ is clear.

Comment: For example, $\sigma \vee\tau \leq t\iff  \sigma \leq t$ or $\tau\leq t$.

Comment: Ah now I see the point: If I want the maximum of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ to be less or equal to t both need to be less or equal to t. And that's why the intersection is used. For the minimum it is enough to require that either $\sigma$ or $\tau$ is less or equal to t. That's why we use here the union.

Thanks for the hint!

Comment: a part of the answer is giving in this post 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232957/min-of-two-stopping-times-is-also-a-stopping-time